# Execute Python script on Android studio Application

Tags: python, android, database, chaquopy, android-scripting

I have developed an android application using java on an android studio. And now I need to implement the python script for a part of the backend functionalities. I want to access the data from our android SQLite DB to process the python scripts and return back to us some values. And on my research, I recovered a plugin named Chaquopy, but it's a paid plugin. so that I need an alternative for the same. Please suggest a tool for the same. Thanks in Advance